# jCarusel + colorbox, show one thumbnail and open different image

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a jcarousel view, a colorbox, and content type that have two fields: thumbnail and full_image. This is because I don't want to be depend on Drupal scaling/cropping . I would like to show thumbnail in jcarousel and after click - open full_image.

In Views there is "Colorbox trigger" field, so I first loaded two hidden fields of both images, and then "Colorbox trigger". I set thumbnail as trigger field, and token of full_image as popup content but it doesn't work (after click, resized thumbnail appears). I feel that I'm just missing something obvious but I'm not sure what. Or maybe is this more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out and I'm putting answer here for future generations. I realized that my invisible Thumbnail field had set colorbox as formatter. It was blocking Colorbox trigger from working. Silly trap, I hope someone will be able to avoid this mistake because of this.